# How to retrieve a unix timestamp from DateTime object within last hour before DST switchover in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, dst

There is an example code

```
<?php
$dt = new \DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$timestamp = 1351383400;    
echo "$timestamp \n";

$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

which outputs 2 different timestamps **1351383400** (Sun, 28 Oct 2012 01:16:40 +0100, right before DST switch) and **1351387000** (Sun, 28 Oct 2012 01:16:40 +0000, 1 hour later, after DST switch)

The question is how can I make the Timestamp getter to return me exactly the same integer that has been passed to the Timestamp setter 1 row before ?

PHP 5.3.6

Comment: I actually think this is a bug.. Might want to try reporting it.

Comment: It seems to be the right answer. Bugs #62561, #62896. fixed in php 5.4

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
    $timestamp = 1181503727;
    echo $timestamp . '<br />';

    $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    echo $dt->format('U');
```

output:
        1181503727
        1181503727